# retrieving URLs from functions within HTML (python)

Tags: html, python-2.7, onclick, web-scraping

I need to scrape some URLs from some retailer product pages, but the specific URLs I need to get aren't in the html part of the page. The html looks like this for each of the items on which one would click to get to the page with the URL I need to grab:

`<div id="name" class="hand bold" onclick="AVON.productcontrol.Go(45714);">ADVANCE TECHNIQUES Color Protection Conditioner Bonus Size</div>`

I wrote the following to get URLs from the page, but since the actual URLs I need don’t seem to be stored in the page, it doesn’t get what I need:

def getUrls(URL):

```
"""input: product page url
    output: list of urls to products
"""
connection = urllib.urlopen(URL)
dom =  lxml.html.fromstring(connection.read())
selAnchor = CSSSelector('a')
foundElements = selAnchor(dom)
urlList = [e.get('href') for e in foundElements]

return urlList
```

Is there a way to get the link that the function after ‘onclick’ (I guess AVON.productcontrol.Go(#);) takes you to? I don’t fully understand html, and while I’ve read a bit about onclick, I can’t figure out how the function after 'onclick' works.

Answer (score 0):

In order to find the URL that you are taken to on click, you need to find the JavaScript source code of the 'Go' function and read and understand it. It's buried somewhere within a  tag or some JavaScript .js file that is referenced directly or indirectly by the HTML page. Happy digging!

Or: you automate the interaction with the web page with a tool like Selenium (http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) and just check where it takes you if you click.